# Задача с базой данных (про игру)

Tags: java, mysql

Попытка объяснить технически:

В базе данных есть следующая структура:

```
objid | id | eventId | value (BIG INT(20))
```

Есть так же набор чисел от 5100 до 5204 включительно.
При определённых условиях, эти числа должны хранится в базе но лишь в одной колонке value (BIG INT(20)). Потом они загружаются и проверяются на наличие уже имеющихся там.

Объяснение по игровому:

Есть квест, который игрок должен выполнить. Ему нужно уработать боссов с ID от 5100 до 5204. После убийства босса, мы должны сохранить результат в базу данных (типо мы его убили и вот наша галочка). При убийствве одного и того же босса, значения проверяются на already exist.

Косяк в том, что создавать на каждого босса значение в базе - нельзя (запретили). Есть лишь одна ячейка,  которую можно менять. И отсюда следует вопрос, как провернуть такое "хак"?

Засунуть в базу такие значения после убийства боссов я могу простым плюсованием, но как вытащить их обратно?

Вместе с боссом к нам в придачу так же попадает весь класс Boss.java, с которым можно играться.

Основная задача это заставить упаковыватсья и распаковываться правильно сохранённое значение в базе.

Структуру кода менять тоже запретили.

не обязательно писать сюда код, направьте туда, где мне надо читать, если есть вариант решения этой задачи.

Спасибо!

Comment: А сколько максимум может быть убитых боссов?

Comment: 105 боссов может быть

Comment: В BIGINT не влезет никак. Если боссов помечать как биты, то нужно 105 битов, а у вас только 64. В два BIGINT можно воткнуть

Comment: ну вот и ответ подъехал, я понятия не имею как в mysql реализуются два биг инта в одной ячейке), пойду читать. Как тут плюсик ставить? ;D

Comment: Никак. Вам нужно две записи.

Comment: 105 (вернее,112) бит - это блоб на 14 байт.